# Cannot install "pycharm-professional": snap "pycharm-professional" has "install-snap" change in progress

Tags: software-installation, snap, pycharm

My Ubuntu edition is 18.04. I need PyCharm to make a Python 3 project but I met the following problem:

[image]

> cannot install "pycharm-professional": snap "pycharm-professional" has "install-snap" change in progress

Comment: As the notification says snap might be busy right now. You can try again later ordownload from website and then install.

Comment: isn't it just because you are already downloading an other application?